# Taking selenium screenshots and displaying on tkinter gui

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a selenium page and display it on a canvas on my tkinter gui, but for some reason I get the error:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
```

This is the code, thanks for any help in advance

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import time
from selenium import webdriver

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')


def picture():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win324\\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get('https://google.co.uk')
    fil = browser.get_screenshot_as_png()
    img = PhotoImage(fil)
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=300,height=300)
    canvas.place(x=12.5,y=450)
    canvas.create_image(20,20, image=img)

Button(root, text='Start', command=lambda: picture()).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: try `PhotoImage(data=fil)`. I don't know if it works or not, but the first positional parameter is a name attribute, not image data. You might need to base64-encode the data before passing it to `PhotoImage`.

Comment: @BryanOakley: It does work with `data` parameter as the *image* returned by `browser.get_screenshot_as_png()` is in **byte** format. It works fine without encoding the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the data as the first positional parameter to `PhotoImage`, but the first positional parameter is for the name rather than the image itself.

You need to provide the data as the value for the `data` attribute:

```
img = PhotoImage(data=fil)
```

Comment: how do i resize this type of image ?

Comment: @coderoftheday: you start by searching this site for how to resize an image with tkinter.

Comment: i did prior to that comment, but unfortunately none have worked

Comment: i get the error ```AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize' ``` and since the screenshot isn't a normal picture some of the 'answers' don't worl

Comment: The intance of `PhotoImage` is a standard `PhotoImage` -- anything you can do with one you can do with the other.

Comment: i don't follow?

Comment: You are creating an instance of `PhotoImage`. It has methods for resizing images. It doesn't care how you created the instance.

Comment: Oh I understand that, but PhotoImage doesn't have a resize method only a zoom method, and zoom doesn't resize the photo

Comment: zoom does indeed resize the photo - that's precisely what its for. Though, it's limited to duplicating pixels rather than resizing to arbitrary sizes.

Comment: yes i figure id need to zoom it in decimals, so id need to get the normal image size then divide it by the canvas size, but apparently ```img has no attribute 'size'```